# DATEPART(MS,datetime) returns incorrect value in SQL Server 2016 databases

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, datepart

I'm running SQL Server 2016, and recently changed the compatibility level of one of our databases to SQL Server 2016 (130).

After that, I noticed the DATEPART function returns the wrong millisecond value from a DATETIME data type, for any value ending in '7'.  This was first noticed in a UDF which converts a datetime and smallint value (the latter containing the milliseconds) into a datetime2(3) value.

For example:

```
DECLARE @datetime_value DATETIME
SET @datetime_value = '2000-01-01 00:00:00.927'
SELECT DATEPART(MS,@datetime_value)
```

returns

`926`

I'm expecting 927.  I've tried this on an SQL Server 2008 instance, and databases compatible with SQL Server 2014, and all these return the correct value.

Is this a known bug, and how can it be addressed?  Casting the value as DATETIME2(3) before passing it to DATEPART function works, however this means updating any functions/procedures which use it.

Comment: There's no such thing as a `datetime(3)` data type on SQL Server, you can't specify precision for that data type. Are you aware that `datetime` has precision of approximately 3.333ms? Ref: [Rounding of datetime fractional second precision](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql#rounding-of-datetime-fractional-second-precision)

Comment: Interesting, this does seem to be the case using DBFiddle and version 2014 vs 2016

Comment: sorry @AlwaysLearning I meant datetime2, I've updated the question.

Comment: The question is still using `datetime`, not `datetime2`

Comment: No repro [in Dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HXrDxkBT) with `datetime2(3)`. I get `927`. I get the expected value both in 2014 and 2016. `datetime` doesn't have millisecond precision so rounding errors like that are known and expected. That's why `datetime` was replaced by `datetime2`

Comment: `this means updating any functions/procedures which use it.` Yes. If you care about milliseconds, you should upgrade to `datetime2`. That's the same as upgrading from `float` to `numeric(7,2)`

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/302362/3690

Comment: @MartinSmith `why they thought this behaviour would be a good idea.` because back in the 1990s, that was the OLE Automation Date format used in COM, VB, VBA, Excel. `datetime2` was introduced in 2008, so the real question is why developers keep using the obsolete type - inertia

Comment: The "why they thought it was a good idea" in my answer there was referring to the bizarre behaviour of inventing extra digits of precision and converting .007 to .006667 etc. I doubt anyone really asked for that and there are plenty of questions from people finding this surprising

Comment: There are no invented digits of precision here; it's a formatting issue that no more than 3 are normally shown. The underlying time value of `'2000-01-01 00:00:00.927'` as a `DATETIME` is actually 278, precisely, in increments of 1/300 of a second, which is 0.926666.... seconds. The consequences of this are indeed surprising, but that has always been the case (like 0.924 rounding down to 0.923333... and 0.925 up to 0.926666...). The real surprise is probably that `DATEPART` doesn't actually round, but perform the moral equivalent of `FLOOR(value_in_seconds * 1000)`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it was the latter part of the question where I was talking about possible solutions, where I referenced datepart(3) instead of datepart2(3) for AlwaysLearning.

The use of datetime is historic, as the result of a vendor-specific database running SQL Server 2008.  I could change the datatype, but would sooner leave it is, and convert to datetime2(3) when the data reaches our own database.

Comment: @MartinSmith Indeed, why change the behaviour and precision of a datatype you're effectively deprecating (by inventing a new, better one) 6 years after the event?

Comment: @JeroenMostert yeah I get it now, I tried DATEPART with a 0.9266666 second value in 2008 and it does as you say, truncating the results to 3 digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This likely stems from a breaking change made back in SQL Server 2016:
[Database Engine: Breaking changes - SQL Server 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/breaking-changes-to-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-ver16)

> Under database compatibility level 130, implicit conversions from **datetime** to **datetime2** data types show improved accuracy by accounting for the fractional milliseconds, resulting in different converted values. Use explicit casting to datetime2 datatype whenever a mixed comparison scenario between datetime and datetime2 datatypes exists. For more information, see this [Microsoft Support Article](https://support.microsoft.com/help/4010261)

Prior to 2016 when a `datetime` was converted to a `datetime2` the **presented** value of the `datetime` was used. In your case, this is `2000-01-01 00:00:00.927`; so as a `datetime2(7)` this resulted in `2000-01-01 00:00:00.9270000`.

As [AlwaysLearning](https://stackoverflow.com/users/390122/alwayslearning) has mentioned, however, `datetime` is accurate to 1/300th of a second, so the `datetime` value `2000-01-01 00:00:00.927` is *actually* `2000-01-01 00:00:00.92666666666~`. As a result in 2016+ the value as a `datetime2(7)` would be converted to the value `2000-01-01 00:00:00.9266667`.

In SQL Server 2014, therefore, when you use `MILLISECOND` for the `DATEPART` you got the `7`, as the value was first rounded up and then the value taken@: `92666666~` -> `927`. On 2016 onwards, however, for recent versions the value is treated as `2000-01-01 00:00:00.92666666666~` and so you get `926`.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now, sort of.  I understand the explanation of what's changed, but I'm struggling with why it's been implemented.  I can certainly understand why Microsoft tell us to explicitly cast to DATETIME2(3), as I will do from now on.  As you say, the cast to DATETIME2(3) will always round the value up, whereas DATEPART will just remove any extra after the first 3 DPs.  That does make datetime behave oddly now to the novice, or if as I, you're dealing with older, inherited databases, and not doing development day-to-day.

Comment: The new methodology is more accurate, @mfarrow.